# is there is any pandas function or a way to extract the required group from dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

This is pandas data frame Here Each **I** which is in the column indicates group
Therefore we have three groups in this data frame
Help to extract the **second group**

**INPUT :**

**I     ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO PQR    STU**
*A              1   2   3   4   5   6       NWEORK

A       3   4   5   6   7   8   CHICAGO

A       4   5   6   7   8   9   CANADA

A       5   6   7   8   9   10  AFRICA

A       6   7   8   9   10  11  America*
                    **I     Name    Region  score   value**
A       JOHN    US  20  2003
A       PETER   UK  10  2003
A       FRANKLIN CANADA 20  2003
A       LEENA   AFRICA  30  2003
**I     SDF SER XDFG    QWE SDFG**
A       1   2   3   4   5
A       1   2   3   4   5
A       1   2   3   4   5
A       1   2   3   4   5

**Required Out Put:**

**I     Name    Region  score   value**
A       JOHN    US  20  2003
A       PETER   UK  10  2003
A       FRANKLIN CANADA 20  2003
A       LEENA   AFRICA  30  2003

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: Can you add code to generate your input dataframe?  You dataframe structure ins't entirely clear with this image.